# Extending OnModelCreating with custom configurations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I have this problem. Right now I'm working on an old piece of software, migrating it from VB to C#.

The problem is the database is in horid state. No foreign keys, no primary keys ...

Anyway, right now my colleague is working on the database. But till he is done I must continue coding my part. But I can't without the damn database (and that's going to take months). So what I have is EF autogenerateed model.

Then I would like to inherit from the context and add fluent-api to my new context and fix what I need by EntityConfigurations and in partial class entities.

The problem is, it just won't work.

Here is my context:

```
public partial class DbTmContext : BaseContext
{
    public DbTmContext() : base()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<DbTmtContext>(null);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ATrialTypeConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new OTrialTypeConfiguration());
    }
}
```

Then I extend the entities:

```
public partial class ATrial
{
    public virtual ICollection<OTrial> OTrials { get; set; }
}

public partial class OTrial
{
    public virtual ATrial ATrial { get; set; }
}
```

And add the configurations...

```
public class ATrialTypeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ATrial>
{
    public ATrialTypeConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(z => z.Id);

        HasMany<OTrial>(z => z.OTrials)
            .WithRequired(o => o.ATrial)
            .HasForeignKey(o => o.Id_ATrial);
    }
}

public class OTrialTypeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<OTrial>
{
    public OTrialTypeConfiguration()
    {
        HasRequired<ATrial>(o => o.ATrial)
            .WithMany(z => z.OTrials)
            .HasForeignKey(o => o.Id_ATrial);
    }
}
```

When I get Otrial object or Atrial object, I cant access the related items. They are just null.

To call the entity I have an repository class. That inherits from the abstract `SqlUnit` class which has the context and implements `IDisposable`

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : SqlUnit, IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    public TEntity Get(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            return Context.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

So to use the EF I just do..

```
        using(Repository<OTrial> sql = new Repository<OTrial>())
        {
            var otrial = sql.Get(522726); <<<<< IS OK
            var atrial = otrial.ATrial; <<<<< WILL BE NULL
        }
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you show to code you are using to get your entities ?

Comment: Ok...I'll add edit.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote and to mark as valid answer if the answer helped you. :)

Comment: It did not help. My problem is not the include bot not existing releationship.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for the `include` method (exemple below) :

```
public static IQueryable<ATrial> GetAll(){
     return context.ATrials
         .Include(t => t.OTrials);
 }
```

What you are doing is a generic way to deal with your entities, but it is not including the related entities by default.

Code a specific getter which use `include` to retreive related entities in this case.

**EDIT** [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) is the related doc.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, when adding an .include I get an System.InvalidOperationException: A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'Model.OTrial' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'ATrial'.

Comment: This is an exemple on what you have to do to get related entities using EF. Keep reading the doc (added in my EDIT) and keep trying, you gonna sort it out.

Comment: It is not advisable to use strings for navigation properties. Use lambda expression. `Include(t=>t.OTrials);`

Comment: @bolkay you are right, I edited my answer accordingly

Comment: I dont think you understand my problem. Those relations are not present in the database, only the columns a there and the model is already build. All those things are something I cant do anything about, so I created new inherited context.